Path Not Found Excetption: Cannot retrieve length of file, path ='assets/images/items_icon.jpg'(OS Error. No such file or directory, errno =2)
I have an error when importing assets,
imagePath: _imageFile != null
            ? _imageFile!.path
            : widget.item?.imagePath ?? 'assets/images/items_icon.jpg',

even though I have the file in assets
enter image description here
i using hive
@HiveField(2)
  final String imagePath;

initialize it in pubspec.yaml
enter image description here

Sometimes, changes to assets require a rebuild. Try to execute commands

flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run


You do not show which widget you're using to show an image
But notice that usually load image from a file path is different load image from asset bundle, because they are located in different folders, one is bundled inside your app, and one is an extra folder.
Eg: if you're using Image widget to load:

asset bundle: Image.asset("assets/images/items_icon.jpg")
file path: Image.file(File(path))

